# matplotlib 3d plot issue

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Am unable to get the proper plot for this, even though i set index 15,15 as 100 , still i get plot with all zero. Can someone help?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make data.
X = np.arange(0, 512, 1)
Y = np.arange(0, 512, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = np.zeros((512, 512), dtype=float)
Z[15,15]=10

# Plot the surface.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


# Plot a 3D surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's too small: See `Z[15:22,15:22]=10` is the smallest size the will show up for 512x512; `Z[15,15]=10` is only visible if the grid is smaller than 55x55.

Comment: @Trenton Mckinney, Thank you for your quick reply
yes it did work if i change Z[15:50,15:50]=10 but is there no possibility to see single value ?

Comment: Apparently only within a given range of values